# SharePoint 2013 - Browser Support

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, explorer-view, mac-os-x

There are some features that doesn´t work in other browsers. An example is the `Open with explorer` (document library) this feature is only working in the Internet Explorer.

**But is it possible to activate this features in other browsers like Chrome or Safari?** The problem is that Mac users are not able to use this function.

Very ironic is that the official Microsoft Edge browser is also not supporting this feature ...

It would be nice if there is a solution for this

Comment: This can help (not a solution): https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_me_in_the_right_direction/2015/08/27/mapping-a-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-connect-to-server-from-mac-osx-finder-does-not-allow-drag-and-drop-of-files-into-a-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: Thanks! But why Edge is not realy supported is some ironic... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't force browsers to support features that aren't available. Browser compatibility is a lot better than it was, there are still things that are reliant on ActiveX controls.

See the Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013 TechNet article. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx